# Changing initial property of the component

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I have a `numberfield` which I set `maxLength` property with `enforceMaxLength`. As a result, the field doesn't accept the value over the `maxLength`, so far so good.

I want to change this `maxLength` property based on the other component value. I tried several way but no success ( it's setting the value but no working ).

The question is, how can I change components initial property after render?

```
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    fieldLabel: 'PROMOSYON TİPİ',
    name: 'PROMO_TYPE',
    id: 'promo_type',
    displayField: 'PROMO_TYPE_NAME',
    valueField: 'PROMO_TYPE_VALUE',
    store: promoType,
    queryMode: 'local',
    inputWidth: 250,
    labelWidth: '280px',
    margin: '0 0 15 0',
    listeners: {
        change: function(cb,nv) {
            if (nv != 0 || nv != 2) {
                var pd = Ext.getCmp('promo_disc');
                Ext.apply(pd, {maxLength: 8});
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    xtype: 'numberfield',
    name: 'PROMO_DISCOUNT',
    fieldLabel: 'PROMOSYON İNDİRİMİ',
    id: 'promo_disc',
    inputWidth: 250,
    labelWidth: '280px',
    margin: '0 0 15 0',
    maxLength: 3,
    enforceMaxLength: true,
    minValue: 0
}
```

Comment: Setting `maxLength` will add a property to the `<input>` tag of your combobox called `maxlength`. So, you could get the `<input>` tag and set the value of the `maxlength` property to the value you want. Or, you could destroy the existing ext component, and create a new combobox with the new maxLength.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @forgivenson idea, I did the following way.

```
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    fieldLabel: 'PROMOSYON TİPİ',
    name: 'PROMO_TYPE',
    id: 'promo_type',
    displayField: 'PROMO_TYPE_NAME',
    valueField: 'PROMO_TYPE_VALUE',
    store: promoType,
    queryMode: 'local',
    inputWidth: 250,
    labelWidth: '280px',
    margin: '0 0 15 0',
    listeners: {
        change: function(cb,nv) {
            if (nv != 0 || nv != 2) {
                    // promo_disc-inputEl is an ID for <input> element
                    Ext.get('promo_disc-inputEl').set({maxlength: 8});
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    xtype: 'numberfield',
    name: 'PROMO_DISCOUNT',
    fieldLabel: 'PROMOSYON İNDİRİMİ',
    id: 'promo_disc',
    inputWidth: 250,
    labelWidth: '280px',
    margin: '0 0 15 0',
    maxLength: 3,
    enforceMaxLength: true,
    minValue: 0
},
```